# Passing data with Google Charts

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to pass data with Google Charts and I am getting an error in the console that reads "Uncaught Error: Every row given must be either null or an array."

I found this post on stackoverflow already however it doesn't seem to be applicable. [Dynamic data with Google Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103951/dynamic-data-with-google-charts). My code is below.

```
 function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
            {"somePercentage":"3.44","someId":"VZ"
            },
            {"somePercentage":"6.95","someId":"XOM"
            },
            {"somePercentage":"5.55","someId":"GG"
            },
            {"somePercentage":"10.53","someId":"INTC"
            },
            {"somePercentage":"8.39","someId":"TD"
            },
            {"somePercentage":"5.59","someId":"VOD"
            },
            {"somePercentage":"12.67","someId":"ARII"
            },
            {"somePercentage":"17.73","someId":"VVVVA"
            },
            {"somePercentage":"21.81","someId":"BSV"
            },
            {"somePercentage":"7.34","someId":"VNM"}
        ]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, looks like you're adding objects as your rows.

what if you do

```
data.addrows([
    ["3.44", "VZ"],
    ["6.95", "XOM"],
    ...
]);
```